# How to get the class name for Java SWT/JFace UI component which is currently highlighted by mouse cursor?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I need to get the name of class that represents the Java SWT/JFace UI component which is currently displayed and highlighted by mouse cursor.

For example, i wish to get something like "org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table" when my cursor is pointing to any displayed SWT Table control, etc.

Tell me, is there a plugin for Eclipse IDE, or any another utility, which allows to do this?

In this way I want to simplify the process of writing UI-tests for Eclipse-RCP plugin project. Searching for class name and path manually anytime when this needed is very discouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install SWT Spy: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/tools.php

Answer (score 2):

Get hold of the current display `Display.getDefault()` and call `getCursorControl()`, once you have the `Control` call `control.getClass().getName()`.

Answer (score 0):

SWT Spy is the correct tool to use. However, the mentioned page is not updated.

From Eclipse 4.7 SWT Spy is included in Eclipse PDE. So you can get it by downloading the Eclipse for RCP and RAP.

To launch SWT Spy, press: CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + F9

In case of doubts, please see: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#swt-spy